# Symfony 3 Form Ajax Post Request Data is Empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I show a list of tags to which I have a little form to add another to that list.

I am completing this form with ajax rather than with symphony doctrine as I want to add something to a list dynamically rather than having a page request.

The HTML code below shows how I have created a form:

```
            <div class="tag-form">
                <form id="tag-form" name="tagging-form" action="{{path('media_bulk_tag_route') }}" method="post">
                <input placeholder="Enter Tag" class="add-tag-input">
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

I then submit this form with Jquery ajax:

```
$('#tag-form').on('submit',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var data = $('form[name="tagging-form"]').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: {request: data},
                        success: function (resp) {
                            var d = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(resp));
                            console.log(d);
                        },
                        complete: function () {

                        }
                    })

                });
```

In my controller I am getting this request and just var dumping it.

```
/**
 * Bulk tagging
 *
 * @Route("/media-tagging", name="media_bulk_tag_route")
 */
public function mediaBulkTag(Request $request)
{
    $request->request->get('request');
    VarDumper::dump($request);
    die();
}
```

Now the problem is when I read this var dump in the network console, the data is empty. Why could this be and what more do I have to do. Thanks.

Here is the full dump:

```
DatabaseController.php on line 125:
Request {#9
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#12
    #parameters: array:3 [
      "_controller" => "MyBundle\Controller\DatabaseController::mediaBulkTag"
      "_route" => "media_bulk_tag_route"
      "_route_params" => []
    ]
  }
  +request: ParameterBag {#10
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "request" => ""
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#11
    #parameters: []
  }
  +server: ServerBag {#15
    #parameters: array:36 [
      "USER" => "vagrant"
      "HOME" => "/home/vagrant"
      "HTTP_COOKIE" => "Phpstorm-5751b086=1fbc46ec-4192-42ec-8d23-628b66cfe7b4; adminer_version=0; PHPSESSID=hmethpqn6bsq493vpuejbg4ulm"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate, br"
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://localhost:8000/media-database"
      "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "*/*"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
      "HTTP_ORIGIN" => "http://localhost:8000"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" => "8"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "localhost:8000"
      "REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "my.bundle"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "80"
      "SERVER_ADDR" => "10.0.2.15"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "55895"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "10.0.2.2"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "nginx/1.11.9"
      "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => "CGI/1.1"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "/home/vagrant/Code/my-bundle/web"
      "DOCUMENT_URI" => "/app_dev.php"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/media-tagging"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/app_dev.php"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "/home/vagrant/Code/my-bundle/web/app_dev.php"
      "CONTENT_LENGTH" => "8"
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
      "QUERY_STRING" => ""
      "FCGI_ROLE" => "RESPONDER"
      "PHP_SELF" => "/app_dev.php"
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1496303912.2553
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1496303912
    ]
  }
  +files: FileBag {#14
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#13
    #parameters: array:3 [
      "Phpstorm-5751b086" => "1fbc46ec-4192-42ec-8d23-628b66cfe7b4"
      "adminer_version" => "0"
      "PHPSESSID" => "hmethpqn6bsq493vpuejbg4ulm"
    ]
  }
  +headers: HeaderBag {#16
    #headers: array:13 [
      "cookie" => array:1 [
        0 => "Phpstorm-5751b086=1fbc46ec-4192-42ec-8d23-628b66cfe7b4; adminer_version=0; PHPSESSID=hmethpqn6bsq493vpuejbg4ulm"
      ]
      "accept-language" => array:1 [
        0 => "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
      ]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
        0 => "gzip, deflate, br"
      ]
      "referer" => array:1 [
        0 => "http://localhost:8000/media-database"
      ]
      "x-requested-with" => array:1 [
        0 => "XMLHttpRequest"
      ]
      "accept" => array:1 [
        0 => "*/*"
      ]
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      ]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [
        0 => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
      ]
      "origin" => array:1 [
        0 => "http://localhost:8000"
      ]
      "content-length" => array:1 [
        0 => "8"
      ]
      "connection" => array:1 [
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
      "host" => array:1 [
        0 => "localhost:8000"
      ]
      "x-php-ob-level" => array:1 [
        0 => 1
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/media-tagging"
  #requestUri: "/media-tagging"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Session {#176
    #storage: NativeSessionStorage {#175
      #bags: array:2 [
        "attributes" => AttributeBag {#171
          -name: "attributes"
          -storageKey: "_sf2_attributes"
          #attributes: & array:1 [
            "_csrf/form" => "177Yjq_CGVSRLnuBjNTVcsQ3a5Tgzi5-lC8DQDpcE9g"
          ]
        }
        "flashes" => FlashBag {#170
          -name: "flashes"
          -flashes: & []
          -storageKey: "_sf2_flashes"
        }
      ]
      #started: true
      #closed: false
      #saveHandler: SessionHandlerProxy {#172
        #handler: NativeFileSessionHandler {#174}
        #wrapper: true
        #saveHandlerName: "files"
      }
      #metadataBag: MetadataBag {#173
        -name: "__metadata"
        -storageKey: "_sf2_meta"
        #meta: & array:3 [
          "u" => 1496303912
          "c" => 1496303203
          "l" => "0"
        ]
        -lastUsed: 1496303903
        -updateThreshold: "0"
      }
    }
    -flashName: "flashes"
    -attributeName: "attributes"
  }
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isForwardedValid: true
}
```

Comment: Where is name tag on your input? Sending values on Form need the "name" attribute. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input doesn't have `name` tag

change this:

```
<input placeholder="Enter Tag" class="add-tag-input">
```

to this for example

```
<input placeholder="Enter Tag" class="add-tag-input" name="your-input">
```

Comment: ahhhhh god dammit. I knew it was something simple. Cheers dude!